# Rename [macosmojave] to [macos-mojave]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-creation-process

Currently, two questions are tagged with **[macosmojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macosmojave)**, which is a misspelling of [macos-mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-mojave), successor of [macos-high-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-high-sierra).

The problem is, I can't retag those two questions to a well-named **[macos-mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-mojave)** tag because I get the following error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [macos-mojave]; however the tag [macosmojave] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the tag from the questions, wait for it to be automaticly deleted and then create the new tag?

Comment: @AndréKool that may interfere with the pending edits: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19942341) and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19942342). And it may be risky to "wait", considering that the popularity of this week's release of the OS may push some users to use [tag:macosmojave] on new questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable request, I'll allow it.

[macosmojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macosmojave) has been renamed to [macos-mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-mojave)